# How can I configure jdee `find-class-source-file` to work with Cassandra source tree?

Tags: java, emacs, jdee

I'm trying to get Emacs+JDEE setup for a Java project I'm about to start on, but I'm having trouble getting JDEE to work properly. The first think that I want to tackle is being able to jump to the source file of a given class name. I'm using the [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org) source as my playground for working with JDEE.

I've setup a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 VM with Emacs 23.3.1 as my test environment. I'm using `openjdk-1.6` from the default Ubuntu repository and JDEE seems to be using it. I downloaded the jdee tar ball and extracted it into `~/.emacs.d`. The Cassandra source tree is checkout into `~/cassandra`. My `~/.emacs.d/init.el` consists of the following:

```
(setq jde-sourcepath '("~/cassandra/src/java"))
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/jdee-2.4.1/lisp")
(load "jde")
```

When I open `~/cassandra/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/ColumnFamily.java` I want to be able to jump to the class `org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData`. When I run `jde-open-class-at-point` on that class name I get the following error:

```
Cannot determine the class of "CFMetaData".
```

Likewise if I run

```
(jde-find-class-source "org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData")
```

I get this error:

```
jde-read-class: No match for CFMetaData
```

What do I need to do to get JDEE to find the source files?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what is wrong exactly, but according to the documents, `jde-open-class-at-point` searches for the source file first in `jde-sourcepath`, then in `jde-global-classpath`, then in `$CLASSPATH`, then in the current directory. So maybe you need to set these varables.

And I post my jdee setting here, hope it can help: (it works well for me)

**.emacs**

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/jdee-2.4.1/lisp")
(autoload 'jde-mode "jde" "JDE mode" t)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (append '(("\\.java\\'" . jde-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
```

And I use `prj.el` for each project:

**prj.el**

```
(jde-project-file-version "1.0")
(jde-set-variables
 '(jde-jdk-registry (quote (("1.6" . "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51"))))
 '(jde-jdk (quote ("1.6")))
 '(jde-xref-db-base-directory "./xrefdb")
 '(jde-xref-store-prefixes (quote ("")))
 '(jde-build-function (quote jde-ant-build))
 '(jde-ant-enable-find t)
 '(jde-sourcepath (quote ("./src")))
 '(jde-built-class-path (quote ("./bin")))
 '(jde-global-classpath (quote ("./bin" "./src" "./lib")))
 '(jde-electric-return-p t)
 '(jde-enable-abbrev-mode t))
```