# emacs-JDEE can not detect files when it compiles

Tags: java, emacs, path, jde

I have two files `A.java` (Base Class) and `B.java` (class). The class `B` succeed `A`. In file `B.java`, I compiled by `C-c C-v C-c`, then it can not detect file `A.java` with error message:

> cannot find symbol

But it works well in compiling manually in terminal.

Also, when I try debugging in JDE, I only get:

> cd: No such directory found via CDPATH environment variable

in mini buffer.

Why are these? How can I fix it?

Comment: Not an answer ..... but have you considered using a real IDE?  Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ, ....

Comment: I like old school :).

Comment: Well you will need to find an old teacher :-)

Comment: like a hippy with birkenstock? damn!

Comment: You may have to provide a `prj.el` file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22600153/1007926  
For projects with multiple modules: https://github.com/jdee-emacs/jdee/issues/44